# Picking the top 10 answers from a survey

Tags: confidence-interval, sample

I ran a survey on a population of advisors in all the different recruitment centers of in a country. I had 1410 text written entries (not multiple choice)
I took a sample of 284 to see what are the top 10 mistakes done by job seekers during interview.

My goal is to infer my result to the population of all advisors (which am defining as the total of 1410 entries). That is, what are the top 10 mistakes done my job seekers during interviews?

Now that I have the proportions of my 284 samples. I am not sure if I need to test first for the normality of my sample or determine another sample and perform an ANOVA test? 
I am simply not sure how to proceed given my stated objective.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

There's no ANOVA to do here - ANOVA relates a dependent variable to one or more independent variables. You haven't got that.  There's also no need for normality.

You have a multinomial distribution. But, you don't want to infer the proportions (which is tricky enough; see [this paper](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~dipankar/bmtry711.11/lecture_03.pdf)) you want to see something about the top 10 in your population, based on the top 10 in your sample.

I doubt there is an analytic solution to this; I think you should try resampling of some sort. That is, simulate a population of 1410 responses with as many different answers as you got. Then repeatedly sample 284 and see how often the top 10 from the 284 match the top 10 from the 1410.